# Getting exception on Genymotion Appium Automation via Selenium Java

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am doing Genymotion automation via using Selenium Java and getting exception while creating driver instance. Can anyone please help me out?

**Code I have designed**-

AndroidDriver

```
driver
        try {
            DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities().android();
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.DEVICE_NAME,"Xiaomi Readmi Note 7");
            cap.setCapability("udid", "192.168.118.102:5555");
            cap.setCapability("deviceManufacturer", "Genymotion");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_VERSION, "4.4.4");
            cap.setCapability(MobileCapabilityType.PLATFORM_NAME, "Android");
            cap.setCapability("appPackage", "com.android.launcher");
            cap.setCapability("appActivity", "com.android.launcher2.Launcher");
            cap.setCapability("noReset", "true");
            cap.setCapability("autoGrantPermissions", "true");
            cap.setCapability("skipUnlock", "true");
            
//                  AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), cap);
            driver= new AndroidDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723"), cap);
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            //      
            driver.findElement(By.xpath("*//[@content-desc='Search']")).click();

        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Getting Exception:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.HttpClient$Factory.createDefault()Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpClient$Factory;
at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:93)
at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.(AppiumDriver.java:97)
at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.(AndroidDriver.java:94)
at mobiledemo.mobiledemo.First_Test.abc(First_Test.java:49)
at mobiledemo.mobiledemo.First_Test.main(First_Test.java:24)

Comment: The error messeage shows the line numbers can you tell us what command refers to each line?

Comment: Line "at mobiledemo.mobiledemo.First_Test.abc(First_Test.java:49)" is referring the code where I am instantiating the driver.

Comment: rest all the initial errors, are referring lines inside the jar library